# Jira rest apis - not understanding which url to use

Tags: authentication, oauth, jira, jira-rest-api

i want to basic authentication using nodejs in documentation. it is written that use "localhost:8080". i am not understanding which url to use. in some other documentation, it is said it deprecated. to make request i am using axios npm package

some things that i tried but didn't work.

```
- axios.get("https://example.atlassian.net",{data:{username:"",password:""}}).then((result) => {})
```

please help me guys? i stucked in this problem from last 2 days. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you

Install with the node package manager npm:

> $ npm install jira-client

```
// With ES5
var JiraApi = require('jira-client');
```

// With ES6

```
import JiraApi from 'jira-client';

// Initialize
var jira = new JiraApi({
  protocol: 'https',
  host: 'jira.somehost.com',
  username: 'username',
  password: 'password',
  apiVersion: '2',
  strictSSL: true
});
```

> Example: Find the status of an issue

```
// ES5
// We are using an ES5 Polyfill for Promise support. Please note that if you don't explicitly
// apply a catch exceptions will get swallowed. Read up on ES6 Promises for further details.
jira.findIssue(issueNumber)
  .then(function(issue) {
    console.log('Status: ' + issue.fields.status.name);
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.error(err);
  });

// ES6
jira.findIssue(issueNumber)
  .then(issue => {
    console.log(`Status: ${issue.fields.status.name}`);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
  });

// ES7
async function logIssueName() {
  try {
    const issue = await jira.findIssue(issueNumber);
    console.log(`Status: ${issue.fields.status.name}`);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}
```

> Documentation

[documentation here](https://jira-node.github.io/)